# Can Firefox's User.js file have conditional user_pref() statements?

Tags: firefox, browser, user-preferences

#### Is it possible to create a conditional `user_pref()` in Mozilla Firefox **user.js**?

I have tried using an `if-else` statement, but the contents of the first `if` statement is executed, even if the given condition is `false`. The contents of the `else` statement is ignored.

**Example #1:**

```
if ( false )
{
    // This is executed even though the given condition is false in Mozilla Firefox user.js.
    user_pref( 'browser.display.background_color', '#000000' );
}

else
{
    // Unfortunately, this is not executed in Mozilla Firefox user.js.
    user_pref( 'browser.display.background_color', '#FFFFFF' );
}
```

---

Additionally, I have also tried using a `ternary` expression to conditionally change a user preference, but the expression is skipped entirely.

**Example #2:**

```
// This is not executed at all in Mozilla Firefox user.js.
user_pref( 'browser.display.background_color', ( 1 === 2 ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF' ) );
```

---

Overall, I am trying to eventually find a way to change `user_pref()` properties conditionally depending on the contents of `window.location.href`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference [the documentation for Firefox's `User.js` file](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file).  Nowhere does it claim that the file takes javascript or any other (Turing complete) programming language.

The file takes either comments or `user_pref()` lines only.

So, conditional statements are not allowed.

However, since **you are modifying styles** in your example, you can accomplish the same thing with user style CSS and/or [the Stylish add-on](https://github.com/stylish-userstyles/stylish/wiki) (recommended).  There you can use some logic, based on the domain and/or URL.

For logic about other, non-style, prefs, you might be able to [write an extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) to do what you wish.

Answer (score -1):

First of all are you sure you want to use `===` and not `==`?  Remember `===` uses a strict conversion and not just typecasting so in most cases `==` will work fine.

Additionally if you are setting some sort of background color of theme it is better to use that data directly instead of just setting it in a preference setting (i.e. storing the value in a variable then storing that in the user.js preference setting).

Comment: Yes, the `1 === 2` is just an example to show a `false` expression, and the question applies to any and all `user_pref()` options.